# mysql,how to back up data to another machine

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a large mysql database in server_1(`OS is Windows`), and I want to copy all the data in server_1 to server_2(`OS is Centos`). I tried export the data in server_1 to sql file and source the sql file in server_2, but it costs a lot of time.

I think write code(`Pandas`) to copy data is a choice, but the data is very large and server_1 and server_2 are not in the sam LAN(they have private IP), consider network congestion，maybe it is not a good choice.

Help you can put forward a good solution.  Thanks!

Comment: If i understood correctly, this will help:
[http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take backup from your windows machine by mysqldump from command line:

```
mysqldump -R --triggers --events -uroot -p<root_pass> --all-databases > c:/backup/mybackup.sql
```

Now move this backup to your centos machine, you can take help of winscp (you can archive if required):

Now restore data by below command:

```
mysql -uroot -p<root_pass> < /backup_path/mybackup.sql
```

**Update1**

single db backup:

```
mysqldump -R -uroot -proot_pass db1 > c:/backup/db1.sql
```

multiple db backup:

```
mysqldump -R -uroot -proot_pass -B db1 db2 db3 > c:/backup/db1_2_3.sql
```

Single/multiple tables backup:

```
mysqldump -uroot -proot_pass db1 tbl1 tbl2 tbl3 > c:/backup/db1_tbl_1_2_3.sql
```

Further as your db size is 1 TB, which will take time even by mysqldump, so you can also simply copy binary even it is not a clean procedure but you can use it.

Step1: Stop your mysql service.

Step2: archive your mysql data directory and move to target machine.

Step3: Stop mysql service on taget machine and take backup of all files which exist in your mysql data directory and clean from here.

Step4: copy all data under mysql directory from backup to your target mysql directory.

Step5: change permission of these copied file under mysql directory by below command.

```
$ chown -R mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Note: Assuming your data directory is /var/lib/mysql

Step6: Start your mysql service.

Note: May be you are getting few warnings in your mysql log file but mysql should work fine.

Comment: Does `mysqldump ` take a long time to back up data? How does its performance?

Comment: About 1 TB. How could I choose specific databse use `mysqldump `, not `--all-databases` or back up databases in MySQL one by one.

Comment: if you want to take single db backup then just remove "--all-databases" and put here your db_name...if you want multiple dbs backup by single command then you can use "-B db1 db2"

Comment: cool, `mysqldump` just takes 5 minutes to back up a 5GB database!

Comment: :)   good, If it is just few GB then mysqldump is perfect but if 1 TB then have to think....